# Mercurial and Bugzilla integration?

Tags: mercurial

I try to make the Mercurial work with my existing Bugzilla setup. however, it didn't work. The local hgrc is attached below for reference.

My question is, how I can trace whether the bugzilla is called/executed once I submit a "hg commit"?

Every time I do a commit, the following error is presented, and I suspect the bugzilla is not executed.

```
[root test01]# hg -v com -m "BZ 686" file
could not import hgext.hgext.bugzilla (No module named hgext.bugzilla): trying        hgext.bugzilla
file
committed changeset 57:0c26a22fc01f
```

If I configured the extension as below, there is no error, but there is no comment insert into the Bugzilla DB. So it means this also does not work.

```
[extensions]
bugzilla = /usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/hgext/bugzilla.py
```

please help!

paul

P.S. below is the content of the hgrc file.

```
============
[extensions]
hgext.bugzilla = 

[ui]
debug = true 
verbose = True

[web]
contact = Admin <db@127.0.0.1>
description = Testing
allow_push = account01
push_ssl = False
baseurl = /HG001/DEV/test01

[hooks]
incoming.bugzilla = python:hgext.bugzilla.hook

[bugzilla]
host = 127.0.0.1
db = bugs
password = db
version = 3.0
strip = 4
bzuser = db@1.0.0.127
hgweb = http://127.0.0.1
bzdir = /var/www/html/bugzilla
template = Changeset {node|short}, made by {author} in the {webroot} repos, refers to this bug.\n
 For complete details, see
 {hgweb}{webroot}?cmd=changeset;node={node|short}\n
 Changeset Description:\n
 \t{desc|tabindent}
```

[usermap]
   hguser=bugzilla.user@domain.com

---

Thanks. BTW, I tried to use the debug mode during the "hg commit". it is found that the hooks are really not being called to execute. any idea?

[root test01]# hg --verbose --debug --traceback --debugger com -m "BZ 686:a" file
entering debugger - type c to continue starting hg or h for help

> /HG001/PD/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(86)_runcatch()
>   (Pdb) b 3
>   End of file
>   (Pdb) r
>   d
>   committed changeset 75:4b90f38e600ac153ec305413345d2836c6358c50
>   --Return--
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(89)_runcatch()->None
>   (Pdb) r
>   --Return--
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(64)dispatch()->None
>   (Pdb) r
>   SystemExit: None
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(27)run()
>   (Pdb) r
>   --Return--
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(27)run()->None
>   (Pdb) r
>   SystemExit: None
>   /usr/local/bin/hg(38)()
>   -> mercurial.dispatch.run()
>   (Pdb)

---

if I run a simple hooks [running hook pretxncommit], I can see it is being executed. but the "incoming.bugzilla" seems not being called.

I also use the "hg help extensions" in my execeution path, the bugzilla extension id enabled.

```
enabled extensions:

 bugzilla
             hooks for integrating with the Bugzilla bug tracker
```

---

[root@ test01]# hg --verbose --debug --traceback --debugger com -m "BZ 686:a" d
entering debugger - type c to continue starting hg or h for help

> /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(86)_runcatch()
>   -> try:
>   (Pdb) r
>   rd

running hook pretxncommit.bug_id_required: ./check_bug_id $HG_NODE
rcommitted changeset 82:dcadb6ed6c0a28a76d25473ab2f5346967e9b103
--Return--

> /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(89)_runcatch()->None
>   -> ui.flush()
>   (Pdb) r
>   --Return--
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(64)dispatch()->None
>   -> return _runcatch(req)
>   (Pdb) r
>   SystemExit: None
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(27)run()
>   -> sys.exit(dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])))
>   (Pdb) r
>   --Return--
>   /HG001/DEV/test01/usr/local/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py(27)run()->None
>   -> sys.exit(dispatch(request(sys.argv[1:])))
>   (Pdb) r
>   SystemExit: None
>   /usr/local/bin/hg(38)()
>   -> mercurial.dispatch.run()
>   (Pdb) r
>   --Return--
>   /usr/local/bin/hg(38)()->None
>   -> mercurial.dispatch.run()
>   (Pdb) r

Comment: You should probably mention your operating system and how you installed Mercurial.

Comment: sorry about that. I complied the Mercurial 2.0.1 from source and installed on Fedora 8 64-bits OS!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum. Please stop posting new details to your question as answers. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

The extension should be just `bugzilla`, as far as I remember.

```
[extensions]
bugzilla =
```

And probably the hook should also be plain `bugzilla.hook` instead of `hgext.bugzilla.hook`.

Comment: the configuration looks ok now, but I am still not able to see the comment is updated to the bugzilla. is there any way to debug the bugzilla extension or make a debug in the extension and see what is going on?

Comment: @user1087418 Sorry, I'm not familiar at all with bugzilla or the bugzilla-extension, just extrapolating from other extensions. You could copy the `bugzilla.py` to `~/.hgext/` and add debugging output to that (changing the config, of course).

Comment: possible to let me know how I can add debug log in those python script?

Comment: @user1087418 If you know a little Python, just print a message `"Doing this and that now"` to a logfile in all interesting places, with return values of functions, if applicable. That may indicate where it fails. If not, well, hope for an expert to answer, google, try on IRC, ...

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I tried to use the debug mode during the "hg commit". it is found that the hooks are really not being called to execute. any idea?

Comment: I used this command to enable the debug. and I found that the simple hooks "pretxncommit.bug_id" can be executed, but not the "incoming.bugzilla".

Comment: Hi, is there any assistant can be provided?